# Paw app on Mac times out when other tools work

Tags: macos, paw-app

I am trying to hit an api at:

https://ozorkauth.herokuapp.com/v1/a

Both with CocoaRestClient and curl from the command line, it works. Paw just times out. Any idea what's going on?

[image: paw]

[image: cocoarestclient]

[image: curl]

Comment: try adding Connection header with keep-alive value or changing HTTP library in Preferences > HTTP

Comment: Definitely, try going to the Preferences (Paw menu > Preferences), tab HTTP, and pick one of the other HTTP libraries to see if this helps. I've just tried hitting your Heroku app, and it responds fine to me (with various HTTP error codes obviously as I don't have OAuth access).